# Is $R=\{(x,y):x-y \in \mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q}\ \forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q}\}$ an Equivalence Relation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, relations, equivalence-relations

Is $R=\{(x,y):x-y \in \mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q}\  \forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q}\}$ an Equivalence Relation

Reflexivity: Obviously it is not Reflexive since $x=\sqrt{2}$ and $y=\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{2}=0$ is rational

Symmetry: It is symmetric since $x-y$ irrational $\implies$ $y-x$ is Irrational

Transitive: Not transitive since $\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{5}$ is Irrational

and $\sqrt{5}-\sqrt{2}$ is irrational but $\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{2}$ is rational.

Hence $R$ is not an Equivalence Relation

Is this approach correct?

Comment: It is correct and it is enough to show that $R$ is not reflexive in order to say $R$ is not an equivalence relation.

Comment: The $R$ in the title and in the first line of the body does not make sense within the scope of "set builder notation".

Comment: I think that it is better to write : $R=\{(x,y);   x,y \in \mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q}:x-y \in \mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q}\}$

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is correct. Good job!

---

*Mostly posting this so this question can be finally considered to have an answer and thus be removed from the unanswered queue. Made it Community Wiki since I have nothing much of substance to add.*